# How to clone github repository without PAT

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone my private github project onto my computer. When I enter my credentials in the console, I get the error-message

```
Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

When I tried to find a solution to access my repository, every suggestion is that it is required to use a PAT.
However I am certain that there is another way, since I can pull/push however I want to that very repository from my laptop, that I am usually working on.
Obviously I don't remember how this is set up, but I'm sure there are not PATs involved, since none exist in my repo-settings.

Comment: Did you laptop clone via ssh?

Comment: I think I did exactly the same for the laptop. Also I don't have any ssh keys neither.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are options:

1. Install the [Git Credentials Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager). It will pop-up the auth prompt and store the token in your operating system's credential store. It comes with recent versions of Git for Windows as well, but needs to be turned on in the inttaller
2. Generate an SSH key and register it in GitHub. You can then authenticate with the SSH key instead if a PAT.

Comment: 1. How does it store the PAT if I didn't create one in GitHub?

Comment: It will generate an oauth token instead  and store that if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @jessehouwing just tried it and it doesn't generate an oauth token at least for GitLab. Seems like PAT is the only way to go or switch to SSH.

Comment: @JakeMilleri don't know what it does and does not support for GitLab, this question was tagged with GitHub. I know for GitHub and Azure DevOps the credential manager can handle the OAuth magic.